# pdfpages doesn't center pdf on page, using Thesis.cls

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pdfpages, thesis

I am using the Thesis-template from http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis.

I have several LaTeX-documents to include in the Appendix. The best solution seems to be compiling each document and using `pdfpages` to include them. I tried `combine`, but there were too many conflicts.

The problem is that, although default `pdfpages`-behaviour should be to center the pdf on the page, it places it in the top-left corner.

Trying to offset it displaces the pages unevenly, as I am using twosided page layout.

I assume this is due to a conflict with the `Thesis.cls`, that it somehow removes any margins and applies it manually for only its own elements.

Any idea how I could either:

- Use the `offset` to place the document appropriately
- Introduce margins for just the pages with the PDF.

Usage:

```
\includepdfset{pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}}

\includepdf[fitpaper=true]{./../Forstudierapport/forstudierapport.pdf}
```

Result:

As you can see, the header is properly placed, but the PDF is displaced.

[image: Image of the page]

Notes:

`\usepackage{geometry}` removes margins from the entire document.

Env: Using BasicTeX 2011 from MacTeX. I'm on Mac OS X.7.

Comment: While code snippets are useful sometimes, a complete MWE will go all the way in helping those who try to solve your problem -- Kindly add a MWE. BTW giving `offset=10mm -14mm` as an option to pdfpages may be helpful to you (you have to adjust the values as suitable).

Comment: I would like to add an MWE, but any document displaying this error would rely on the Thesis.cls and its required packages in order to display the error.

Comment: I researched further. The problem only occurs when using Thesis.cls

The issue is a conflict between Thesis.cls' layout and pdfpages. On both odd and even sides the pdf-page is inserted in the upper left corner. Asking pdfpages to offset the document moves it (correctly) from the centre and outward. This does however position one of the two correctly, while the other moves of canvas.

I tried something similar to:

`\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\ifodd{\addtolength{2in}{1.75in}}\fi}]{document.pdf}`

Any idea what command might add the necessary margins in the `pagecommand`?

Comment: Another solution would be to make pdfpages ignore the fact that the document is twoside– making it believe it is oneside.

Comment: The main problem is that `Thesis.cls` uses `vmargin` to set the page parameters. This package is incompatible with `pdfpages`, unfortunately. You should try and persuade the authors to use `geometry`: it's not a big deal to change the few relevant lines in `Thesis.cls`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is that `Thesis.cls` uses `vmargin` to set the page parameters. This package is incompatible with `pdfpages`, unfortunately; actually it's incompatible with `atbegshi` which is called by `eso-pic`.

I know because I found the same issue when some user had similar problems with my `frontespizio` package that uses `atbegshi`.

You should try and persuade the authors to use geometry: it's not a big deal to change the few relevant lines in `Thesis.cls`.

The same setting can be obtained with `geometry` with

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{includehead,includefoot,
  left=1.5in,right=1.0in,
  top=0.6in,bottom=0.8in,
  headheight=20pt,headsep=0.25in,
  footskip=0.3in}
```

Comment: Modified Thesis.cls as you suggested, by removing the (two) references \vmargin and \setmarginXX. 
Then simply adding `\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}` solved the problem perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: In my case, I had to replace `\usepackage{vmargin}` with *egreg*'s geometry commands and remove the `\setmarginsrb` command a few lines down.

Comment: @egreg Kindly take a look on this question also..tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286317/how-set-margins-to-print-when-pdf-files-are-inserted I am sorry. I dont know how to contact you for this question. Thats why I am giving as a comment in this question.

Answer (score 3):

I am also writing my thesis. However, I am using a different template that is based on the **book** standard class. I saw that the problem with **twoside** and **pdfpages** is around for more than a decade and I did not get it working with any of the proposed solutions here and elsewhere.

Therefore, I come up with an alternative solution. Use a **forloop** and include every page of a given pdf document with **includegraphics**. You need the corresponding packages as shown below. Please change the number of total pages in the forloop (here 42) as required:

```
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcounter{ct}
\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 42}
{
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,page=\value{ct}]{mypdf}
    \newpage
}
```